# How to get the current URL of an external page loaded in a jqModal window?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jqmodal

Is it possible to get the current URL of an external page loaded in a jqModal window?
And further, in the implementation of the jqModal, in where the external page is located? `iframe` or `div`?

Comment: Anyone can help me to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access the inner url of an iframe, I think that's blocked for security reasons.

There are probably tricks you can play if the "external" page is under your control (send ajax messages to the parent page)